# vmmem has high memory usage, even though nothing is running. (Not due to wsl or sandbox)

Tags: windows-10, memory

**vmmem** memory usage:

[image: vmmem memory usage]

wsl2:

[image: wsl2]

[Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koA7H.png)

The process uses almost 0.5 GB, even though `wsl2` is not running and there is no `hyper-v` virtual machines running. What can I do?

System: Windows 10 22H2

Comment: How long has it been since you stopped using WSL 2 terminals/processes? What is the output of `hcsdiag list`?

Comment: @harrymc No, nothing there works. The only thing that seemingly works is killing the vmmem process in process hacker, then its memory usage reduces to 56kb

Comment: @DanielB the output only shows CmService

Comment: Unfortunately internet resources aren't entirely sure what this type of VM is, but it could be related to Windows Sandbox. Do you use that?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, on my machine windows sandbox is enabled.

Comment: It does indeed look like the _CmService_ VM is related to Sandbox, I also have it now after enabling Sandbox. // Which program are you using to show the memory usage? It may present inaccurate or misleading information. Because for me, the process only has 8 KiB active working set, the rest is paged out.

Comment: @DanielB I'm using process hacker to show its commit charge.

Comment: Not a duplicate by the way because this isn't about WSL.

Comment: Setting CmService to start on demand solves the problem.